# How to get the portal coordinates from the intel map?

Tags: ingress

It's my first question here.
I'm playing ingress and making a tool to calculate distances between portals and level of portals to link them. It's using static portal coordinates, which are written in code.

Now I want to take the coordinates from the map at [ingress.com/intel](http://ingress.com/intel), but I can't find a way to do it. Ideally, I would like all to find the coordinates of all portals visible on the map and write them to a file.

Is anybody experienced with making plugins for Ingress?

**How do I get the coordinates (and titles) of all portals visible on the Ingress intel map?**

Comment: This sounds more like a question fit for gamedev.se?

Comment: @JamesJiao I concur, definitely sounds like a gamedev question.

Comment: Oops! Sorry for this.

Answer (score 4):

Must have changed now because if you hit "Link" while you have a portal selected you get both the maps Long/Lat (LL) as the first set of coordinates and the Portal Long/Lat (PLL) as the second set of coordinates.

Example: Big Ben

http://www.ingress.com/intel?ll=51.500691,-0.129092&z=17&pll=51.500775,-0.124466

Answer (score 3):

Use your browser's dev console and save json response to /r/getEntities call -- this includes coordinates of all portals, edges (links) and regions (fields) in current tile.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Install iitc
2. Search and add the plugin **ingress dual map exporter**
3. Click on the right side on **IDM Export**

A prompt with the information will open, it will contain data like that:

```
"Central Business Park",53.260177,-7.487942
"Fountain in Town Park ",53.272818,-7.49838
"Tullamore Post Office",53.2744,-7.492972
"The Bridge House",53.274933,-7.492685
"Tullamore Presbyterian Church",53.272192,-7.494551
"Lloyd Town Park Main Street Gate",53.273133,-7.499619
"Town Park Gate",53.271298,-7.496134
"Town Park Sandpit",53.271369,-7.497227
"Bicycle Art Tullamore",53.270381,-7.499697
"Tullamore Station",53.271347,-7.502425
"Joseph Flanagan Keystone",53.274166,-7.493055
"Spollens Bar",53.272986,-7.493688
"ONE Memorial Monument",53.271111,-7.498611
"Tullamore Train Station, Tullamore, Co. Offaly, Ireland",53.270394,-7.500745
```

Answer (score 1):

I warn you- this IS what you asked in the original version of the question but it is not valid for the tool you are making:

If the portal was mentioned in the Intel communication chat (for example attacked by somebody, ), in the source code ('inspect element' in Google Chrome) you will find something like:

```
<div class="pl_content pl_narrow">
    Your Portal 
    <span class="pl_portal_name" ontouchstart="panto( 48.691753 ,  6.178264 )" onclick="panto( 48.691753 ,  6.178264 )">
        Mat de Dombasle
    </span>
    <span class="pl_portal_address" ontouchstart="panto( 48.691753 ,  6.178264)" onclick="panto( 48.691753 ,  6.178264 )">
        (1 Place Dombasle, 54000 Nancy, France)
    </span> 
    is under attack by
    <span class="RESISTANCE pl_nudge_player" ontouchstart="nudge('@Pharaoh12', event)" onclick="nudge('@Pharaoh12'), event">
        Pharaoh12
    </span>
</div>
```

Here you have the complete name and coordinates of the portal...

I know that this gives you only portals that have been interacted with, but I did not think it would be good as just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is in the link. Click on the portal then click link and select the destination portal. Copy the link and the geo location is in there.

PORTAL:
40.683298,-74.005799

DESTINATION:
40.685883,-74.002196

https://intel.ingress.com/intel?ll=40.686638,-73.976477&z=14&pls=40.683298,-74.005799,40.685883,-74.002196

Answer (score 0):

There is a Button at the top right corner of the Map called "Link". Press on it and copy the url and you will get what you want.

Comment: This is not what was asked. With the Link functionality you get the coordinates of the center of the map you're actually viewing, not the coordinates of the portals.

Comment: @Kappei You actually get both, the center's and the selected portal's (if selected) coordinates.